# I dont know how using LOGOUT in FACEBOOK API ANDROID

Tags: android, facebook-login

I have the follow code, but I don't know which is the method that execute when I push in Logout. I only need know which is the method that execute in logout. Or another solution? Thanks for all :) dasasa

```
public class FBLoginFragment extends Fragment implements IServiceCallback {

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private TextView textView;

private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
                mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
            }
        };
        mProfileTracker.startTracking();
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        displayMessage(profile);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};

public FBLoginFragment() {

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    accessTokenTracker= new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

        }
    };

    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
            displayMessage(newProfile);
            if(newProfile != null){
                register(newProfile);
            }

        }
    };



    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
        return;
}

private void displayMessage(Profile profile){
    if(profile != null){
        textView.setText(profile.getName());
    }
}

private void register(Profile profile){
    if(profile != null){
        new Register(this).run(profile);
    }

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    displayMessage(profile);
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(JSONObject obj, String method) throws JSONException {
    User user = new User(obj);
    user.insert();

    //Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Update.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onError(String error) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the active Session, then then call [`closeAndClearTokenInformation()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/Session/).

You can get the currently active session via `Session.getActiveSession()`.

Comment: but, where? in which method?

Comment: Wherever you wish to log the user out. Where you do that is completely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to logout from facebook programmatically in android

/**
 * Logout From Facebook 
 */

public static void callFacebookLogout(Context context) {

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null) {

    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        //clear your preferences if saved
    }
} else {

    session = new Session(context);
    Session.setActiveSession(session);

    session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        //clear your preferences if saved
  }
```

}